# jQuery string manipulation performance vs. PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Im building a custom jquery modal box that loads an external html template file that contains variables that need to be replaced.  For instance: [user-name]

**I know I have 2 options for modifying the template file:**

- use find and replace in jquery
- process the template server side and
  simply send the result to jquery

From a user performance stand point, which would be faster?

Comment: This is a pretty open-ended, subjective question, and you really haven't provided much in the way of specifics. Would using PHP require an additional HTTP request? How much other work is your server already doing? How much other work is the browser already doing? Are you already using jQuery? Also, what is _"user performance?"_ You're not asking users to perform, are you? :P

Comment: agreed there is not a lot of info, but I guess the question is simply "which form of string manipulation is faster from a user perceived performance viewpoint"

Comment: Well considering Javascript is client side and PHP is server side... it depends. If the user have a crappy internet connection but a great computer, jQuery is probably faster. If the server have high traffic... once again jQuery could be faster. If they have a crappy computer... perhaps PHP is better. Then again if they don't have javascript enable... lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a user point of view it would be faster to use jquery . you don't loose time by sending and reciveing data from the server

Answer (score 0):

Not having any details about why you're asking, I would say that it probably doesn't matter.